# Verify Remote Server X509Certificate using CA Certificate File

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, sslstream

I've generated a CA and multiple certificates (signed by CA) using OpenSSL and I have a .NET/C# client and server both using `SslStream` which each have their own certificates/keys, mutual authentication is enabled and revocation is disabled.

I'm using `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` for `SslStream` to validate the remote server's certificate and I was hoping I could just load the CA's public certificate (as a file) in the program and use it to verify the remote certificate rather then actually installing the CA in the Windows Certificate Store. The problem is the `X509Chain` won't show anything else unless I install the CA into the store, either will the Windows CryptoAPI shell when I open a PEM version of one of the certificates.

My question is, how can I verify a certificate has been signed by my specific CA just by using the CA's public certificate file **without using Windows certificate store or WCF** when `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`, `X509Certificate` and `X509Chain` don't seem to give me anything to work with?

Comment: I don't understand why adding the CA certificate to the Windows Store causes X509Chain to show it in the chain but if I don't it's not part of it. Is there someone to add the CA certificate to the chain within the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback?

Comment: I still can't find an answer to this :(

Answer (score 10):

Because the CA certificate is NOT in the root certificate store, you will have within the *RemoteCertificateValidationCallback()* an error flag of *SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors* ; a possibility is to validate explicitely the certificate chain against your own *X509Certificate2Collection*, since you are not using the local store.

```cs
if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
{
    X509Chain chain0 = new X509Chain();
    chain0.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    // add all your extra certificate chain
    chain0.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(new X509Certificate2(PublicResource.my_ca));
    chain0.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
    isValid = chain0.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
}
```

You can also re-use the chain passed in the callback, add your extra certificate(s) in the *ExtraStore* collection, and validate with the *AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority* flag which is needed since you add untrusted certificate(s) to the chain.

You could also prevent the original error by adding programmatically the CA certificate in the trusted root store (of course it opens a popup, for it is a major security problem to globally add a new trusted CA root) :

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2 ca_cert = new X509Certificate2(PublicResource.my_ca);
store.Add(ca_cert);
store.Close();
```

**EDIT:** For those who want to clearly test the chain with your CA :

Another possibility is to use the library `BouncyCastle` to build the certificate chain and validate the trust. The options are clear and errors are easy to understand. In cas of success it will build the chain, otherwise an exception is returned. Sample below :

```
// rootCerts : collection of CA
// currentCertificate : the one you want to test
var builderParams = new PkixBuilderParameters(rootCerts, 
                        new X509CertStoreSelector { Certificate = currentCertificate });
// crls : The certificate revocation list
builderParams.IsRevocationEnabled = crls.Count != 0;
// validationDate : probably "now"
builderParams.Date = new DateTimeObject(validationDate);

// The indermediate certs are items necessary to create the certificate chain
builderParams.AddStore(X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(intermediateCerts)));
builderParams.AddStore(X509StoreFactory.Create("CRL/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(crls)));

try
{
    PkixCertPathBuilderResult result = builder.Build(builderParams);
    return result.CertPath.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate>();
    ...
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use the library `BouncyCastle` to build the certificate chain and validate the trust. The options are clear and errors are easy to understand.

Comment: See the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/27310276/1038496 here for proper check of your own CA. The method done above will accept every CA (no checks for validity).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I verify a certificate has been signed by my specific CA just by using the CA's public certificate file without using Windows certificate store or WCF when RemoteCertificateValidationCallback, X509Certificate and X509Chain don't seem to give me anything to work with?

The following code will avoid the Windows certificate stores and validate the chain. Its a little different than JB's code, especially in the use of flags. The code below does not require `AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority` (but it does use `X509RevocationMode.NoCheck` since I don't have a CRL).

The name of the function does not matter. Below, `VerifyServerCertificate` is the same callback as `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` in `SslStream` class. You can also use it for the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in `ServicePointManager`.

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        String CA_FILE = "ca-cert.der";
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2(CA_FILE);

        X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
        chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

        // Check all properties
        chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        // This setup does not have revocation information
        chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        // Build the chain
        chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        // Are there any failures from building the chain?
        if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
            return true;

        // If there is a status, verify the status is NoError
        bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
        Debug.Assert(result == true);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have *not* figured out how to use this chain (`chain2` below) by default such that there's no need for the callback. That is, install it on the ssl socket and the connection will "just work". And I have *not* figured out how install it such that its passed into the callback. That is, I have to build the chain for each invocation of the callback. I think these are architectural defects in .Net, but I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: It looks ok. The `chain2` will be the list of certificate trust between the tested cert and the root cert. Nowadays, you might want to use the BouncyCastle library if you perform advanced operations on certificates.