# Validation of certificate for client

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am creating an application which uses EWS (Exchange Web Service) to move mails. I am able to run my application by bypassing certificate validation. I use this code to bypassing certificate validation:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
             X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   { 
        return true; 
   };
```

To verify certificate I followed [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx) which was very helpful in finding the certificate and checking the certificate.

While using that post **ValidateCert** method was throwing exception

```
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online | X509RevocationMode.Offline;
```

The exception is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal enum value: value.
at
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainPolicy.
             set_RevocationMode(X509RevocationMode value)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I am open to any other approach to do the same task.

Comment: Looks like the example is either wrong or obsolete. X509RevocationMode enum can't be used as Flags , just pick 1 of the three value.

Comment: Can you please me some way to do this stuff.

Comment: `X509RevocationMode.Online | X509RevocationMode.Offline` - pick one or the other. If you choose `X509RevocationMode.Online`, then you might DoS your application while downloading a large CRL (or attempt to download a missing CRL).

Comment: Also see [Verify Remote Server X509Certificate using CA Certificate File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695438/verify-remote-server-x509certificate-using-ca-certificate-file/22703198). Its got a working example of server verification, including loading a CA from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You must choose either `Online` or `Offline`:

- `Online`: always tries to contact the CDP or OCSP url specified in the certificate to get the CRL list to check the revocation
- `Offline`: tries to use an existing cached copy of the CRL

The first option can be slow, if the CDP or OCSP server is not responding, if there are connectivity problems, and so on. It can even fail if this problem is permanent.

I'd recommend using the second option, for most cases. The only reason not to use the cached copy of the CRL is that there has been recent certificate revocations and that they have just been published to the CRL. Besides, the CRL have expiration dates, which will force to get a new copy if they have expired.

You can also clear the CRL cache before starting the process with the offline option. Google it: there are different options. You'll need to use `certutil.exe`.