# WCF Communication through SSL : Issue with WCF access due to Third-party Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Tags: .net, wcf, security, ssl

I have a WCF service which uses certificate authentication with Transport security. The service is deployed in a windows service, uses wshttp binding.

When I try to access the service in debug mode or after deployed as a service in local machine, I always get the error " The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme Anonymous"

After breaking my head for a week, I stumbled upon this KB article from Microsoft

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801679

> KB 931125 Package installed more than 330 Third-party Root Certication Authorities. Currently, the maximum size of the trusted certificate authorities list that the Schannel security package supports is 16 kilobytes (KB). Having a large amount of Third-party Root Certication Authorities will go over the 16k limit, and you will experience TLS/SSL communication problems.

I tried their solution of deleting the third party trusted authorities and found that I cant even browse to Google or any https enabled site.

But the solution worked and I was able to make the calls to my WCF service.

Right now I have restored the third party trusted authorities from the KB link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125 since I cannot access many sites, and vpn, email does not work.

After the restore, again I am unable to access my WCF service.

What is the best way to resolve this?

I got the solution now, need to do the following

Source http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/156768-KB-931125-being-installed-with-no-easy-removal

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to resolve this?

In .Net, we can use one CA rather than the 330+ form the entire store. [Programming WCF Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526993.do) by Juval Lowy discusses using the server's certificate around page 570. Lowy talks about validation and `IEndpointBehavior` and `X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication`.

However, I can't tell if WCF has the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` like in `SslStream` and `ServicePointManager`? If its available, use the one CA you need and load it from the filesystem:

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        String CA_FILE = "ca-cert.der";
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2(CA_FILE);

        X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
        chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

        // Check all properties
        chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        // This setup does not have revocation information
        chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        // Build the chain
        chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        // Are there any failures from building the chain?
        if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
            return true;

        // If there is a status, verify the status is NoError
        bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
        Debug.Assert(result == true);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have *not* figured out how to use this chain (`chain2` above) by default such that there's no need for the callback. That is, install it on the ssl socket and the connection will "just work". And I have *not* figured out how install it such that its passed into the callback. That is, I have to build the chain for each invocation of the callback. I think these are architectural defects in .Net, but I might be missing something obvious.

A similar answer shows up in a couple of questions like [Verify Remote Server X509Certificate using CA Certificate File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695438/verify-remote-server-x509certificate-using-ca-certificate-file).

Comment: The problem I have is that the client is unable to do handshake and hence unable to send the certificate to the call. I already have this in my code for testing

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
            {
                return true;
            };